# Status code error while fetching JSON data

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am trying to Extract JSON data from URL with parameters to it and code is as follows:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)
import urllib2

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
if request.method == 'POST':
    #user inputs
    valueone= request.form.get('first')
    valueTwo = request.form.get('second')
    valueThree = request.form.get('third')
    #api call 
    data = {"perfid" : {0}, "section" : {"hostname" : {1}, "iteration" : {2}, "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"}}
    req = urllib2.Request('http://api-latx-dev.corp.netapp.com/ws/spm/spm-general', json.dumps(data)) 
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    the_page = response.read()
    url=response.getcode()
    returnData = {}
    if url.status_code == 200:
        returnData["status"] = "SUCCESS"
        returnData["result"] = the_page
        return jsonify(returnData)
    else:
        returnData["status"] = "ERROR"
        return jsonify(returnData)
    #jsonify(response.json())
return render_template('index.html')
```

I need to fetch data But getcode() gives int which is not working with "if url.status_code == 200".Can anyone please suggest how to deal with it.

Comment: `data = {"perfid" : {0}, "section" : {"hostname" : {1}, "iteration" : {2}, "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"}}`, there is no value for `{0}, {1}, {2}`

Comment: I hard coded it by putting it as  :  data = {"perfid" :valueone, "section" : {"hostname" : valueTwo, "iteration" : valueThree, "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"}}